Capacitor and Google Analytics 4 GA4
We have implemented GTM in our PWA, which we have then built for Android and iOS using CapacitorJS.
While GTM is working well through Android, all traffic on iOS is being blocked by GTM. We believe this is due to the app URI starting with capacitor:// and not https://
We’ve seen an old fix, which seems to have only worked for UA, as per [https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/issues/1433#issuecomment-644086704][1]
Set Field Name to checkProtocolTask with Value as {{Empty function}}
Set Field Name to storage with Value as none
Set Field Name to hitCallback with Value as {{JS - SetClientId}}
Set Field Name to clientId with Value as {{JS - GetClientId}}

The intention of this is to bypass the protocol check, but this seems to now work anymore.
We know that Firebase for Capacitor is possible. However, we’d rather not reimplement all app analytics and we’d love to be still able to lean on the advantages of defining events from GTM itself.
Any help would be appreciated.
